# i want to write custom sql query to select low and high price in magento2?

Tags: controllers, catalog-price-rules, magento-2.1.3, query, special-price

I want to write a custom sql query to find final price,min-price,max_price,special_price but i dont know in which file i suppose to write this code and execute?

can anyone tell me where we can write our custom sql query code like suppose in my case to filter price based on final price,min-price,max-price and to return result on category list page in magento 2.

like if i selected product price by low or high,it should display result accordingly.
this is my code:

```
<select id="sorter" data-role="sorter" class="sorter-options selectpicker">
    <?php foreach ($block->getAvailableOrders() as $_key => $_order): ?>
        <?php if($_order != 'Price'): ?>
        <option value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_key; ?>"
            <?php if ($block->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?>
                selected="selected"
            <?php endif; ?>
            >
            <?php //echo $block->escapeHtml(__($_order == "Position" ? 'Relevance': $_order)) ?>
            <?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__($_order)) ?>
        </option>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php 
        $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $path = strstr($url, '?'); 
    ?>
    <option 
        <?php if($path == '?product_list_order=price&product_list_dir=asc'): ?>
            selected="selected" 
        <?php endif; ?> 
        class="low-high" >
        Price - Low to High
    </option>
    <option 
        <?php if($path == '?product_list_order=price&product_list_dir=desc'): ?>
            selected="selected" 
        <?php endif; ?> 
        class="high-low" >
        Price - High to Low
    </option>
</select>
```

but it is not filtering the result in correct manner.iam unable to get price from low-high or vice versa when i select filters.

could any one tell me that do we need to write custom sql code in a controller or block. and in which exact file i need tow write the code to get result when i sort product based on price.i also need a special price query where the result can be shown based on final_price and it should include special price if that product is having it.

Answer (score 0):

try to make an observer on your action.

Here are all the actions in magento 2 https://cyrillschumacher.com/magento2-list-of-all-dispatched-events/

after this you can use this code to make a query by modify for your need:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
            $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
            $connection = $resource->getConnection();
            $tableName = $resource->getTableName('eav_attribute_option_value'); 
            $sql = "Select `value` FROM " . $tableName . " where `option_id` =".$health_insurance_id. "";
            $healthAtt = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
             $health_insurance = $healthAtt[0]['value'];
```

Comment: how to do it sir can u please explain in brief .i mean how to make action for observer and in which file.iam new to magento

Comment: i use make observer in inheriting which class is it Magento_catalog/Observer  or Magento_Bundle
which class to inherit sir

Comment: any reply please sir?

Comment: any clue regarding this query sir

Comment: can you be more specific about what you need?

Comment: in actual i need a custom filter on category landing page which shows price-High To Low and vice versa. I have implemented one solution like i have mentioned above but its not working at all.products are not filtering based on high /low price...iam very new to magento2 so i have less knowledge about creating observer and event but this really is an issue of creating observer for the same.

Comment: this is my site sir and u can check on catgeory page that filters are not showing details
http://magento2.shelltag.com/women/bags/backpacks

select filter price-High to low and vice versa and u will know what is the issue

Comment: in that case, please check the price attribute in you backend and see how you can use this attribute in filter. i think it's very easy.

Comment: go to store-> attirbutes->product-> search for price-> go on attribute-> storefront properties-> Use in Layered Navigation-> select filtrable(with reults)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55320/discussion-between-alin-lupoiu-and-yogesh-raghav).

Comment: sir i have left details in chat.kindly check and i dont want any change in layer navigation filter but in search filter on category list page

Comment: any idea please?

Comment: kindly any reply will  be appreciable?